# How to display uploaded image using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to upload an image and display that image without reloading the page How I can implement this. I think we can do this using Ajax form submission. I tried the following code but Ajax form submit function is not working. Is there any mistake in this code tell me how to implement this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
              $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function()
                 { 
                    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
                }); 

            });
    </script>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="" method="post"> 
          <input type="file" name="image_name" id="image_name" >
       </form>
    </body>
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: you are doing wrong file is not posted in form via ajax,,you need to post it in normal form

Comment: use jquery uploadify,  you will be able to accomplish your need with that

Comment: can I implement  jquery uploadify in html 4?

Comment: yes i posted the code in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the JQuery-form plugin, you will be able to send images. Your code is correct but has some small errors.

You have to call the submit method of ajaxForm to make the ajax call, and you need to add a callback to the complete event of AjaxForm.(Here, I've added the event onchange, so that, only when the user selects an image, then the ajax call will be fired.)

This works -

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Added an onchange event.
    $("#image_name").on('change',function(){
        $("#myForm").ajaxForm(
            {complete:  function(data){
                             alert("Thank you for your comment!");
                        }
            }
        ).submit();
    });
});
</script>

<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="a.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="image_name" id="image_name" >
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do someting like this using uploadify plugin, i did this way to do uplaod image via ajax,after file is uploaded in uploadAllComlete function set image tage src to the url where file is stored on server via upload and you are done:

```
 <input type="file" name="fileUpload" value="" id="fileInput1" /> 
                 <p><a href="javascript:$('#fileInput1').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a></p>
```

Here is javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $("#fileInput1").uploadify({
        'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf")',
        'script': '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Upload")',
        'auto': false,
        'multi': false,
        'expressInstall': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.4/expressInstall.swf")',
        'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify-v2.1.4/cancel.png")',
        'scriptAccess': 'always',
        'hideButton': false,
        'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts': ' *.jpg; *.png',
        'fileDataName': 'uploadedFile',
        'sizeLimit': 1000000000,
        'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
            $('#UploadedPicture').val('');
            $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', '');
            $('#uploadedImage').hide();
            //alert("name: " + fileObj.name + " error type: " + errorObj.type + ", info: " + errorObj.info);
        },
        'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
            //alert("allcomplete => " + data.filesUploaded + ":" + data.errors + ":" + data.allBytesLoaded + ":" + data.speed);
        },
        'onCheck': function () {
            //alert("oncheck");
        },
        'onComplete': function (event, id, fileObj, response, data) {

            //alert("oncomplete => " + ":" + fileObj.name + ":" + fileObj.filePath + ":" + fileObj.size + ":" + response);
            $('#fileInput2').val(fileObj.name);
            $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', '/uploads/' + fileObj.name);


        },
        'onOpen': function (event, id, fileObj) {
            //alert("onopen => " + ":" + fileObj.name + ":" + fileObj.filePath + ":" + fileObj.size);
            var temp = fileObj.name.split('(');
            var filename = $.trim(temp[0]);
            $('#UploadedPicture').val('~/uploads/' + filename);
            $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', '/uploads/' + filename);
            $('#uploadedImage').show();
        },
        'onProgress': function (event, id, fileObj, data) {
            //alert("onprogress => " + ":" + fileObj.name + ":" + fileObj.filePath + ":" + fileObj.size + ":" + data.percentage + ":" + data.bytesLoaded + ":" + data.allBytesLoaded + ":" + data.speed);
        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) { alert('test'); $('#fileInput2').val(file.name); },
        'onUploadComplete': function (file) {
            //alert('The file ' + file.name + ' finished processing.');
        },
        'onCancel': function (file) {
            $('#UploadedPicture').val('');
            $('#uploadedImage').attr('src', '');
            $('#uploadedImage').hide();
        }
    });

    </script>
```

here is my server side function on which file is posted:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
        {
            if (uploadedFile.ContentLength == 0) return new EmptyResult();

            string[] temp = uploadedFile.FileName.Split('(');
            string FileName = temp[0].Trim();
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), uploadedFile.FileName);
            uploadedFile.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Comment: this plugin will upload image or file via ajax, your page state will be saved and no postback

Answer (score 0):

i used this to upload image using ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = $('form');
    var l = $('#loader'); // loder.gif image
    var b = $('#button'); // upload button
    var p = $('#preview'); // preview area

    b.click(function(){
        // implement with ajaxForm Plugin
        f.ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function(){
                l.show();
                b.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                p.fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(e){
                l.hide();
                f.resetForm();
                b.removeAttr('disabled');
                p.html(e).fadeIn();
            },
            error: function(e){
                b.removeAttr('disabled');
                p.html(e).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```